# How to remove protection from Excel document generated by jasperreports

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I'm using ireport 5.1.0, when i export the report into Excel format. my Excel document cells are protected by default, i have to remove the protection manually in the MS Excel Menu.

Can i get exported Excel document without protection by default.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file and the *Java* code (if you have)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I just tried in batch mode and the problem disappeared.
The problem only occurs when I generate the document with ireport.
and that it does not matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property [net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.locked](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.locked) to `false` by adding this element to the top of your JRXML file (right below the `<jasperReport ...>` opening tag):

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.locked" value="false" />
```